# Imposing conditions for parameters when fitting a curve

Tags: r, curve, maple

I am trying to fit some points to a function of the form f(A)=a·(1-exp(-21.6·A))+b·A+c·A^2+d·A^3. I want this function to satisfy the condition f(1)=1, so provided that exp(-21.6) is small, I approximate this condition by d=1-a-b-c.

The problem is that I also want the function f(A)-A to not have any zeros in the interval (0,1). Performing some calculations, that means that we have some upper (or lower) bounds for a, b, and c, but I don't know how to impose these bounds for the fitting (or maybe another better method), not in Maple nor R, as setting initial values does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could look at [Rsolnp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsolnp/Rsolnp.pdf) package. You may want to doublecheck whether it will suit your problem (for fitting a specific curve some distance metric might be needed, so I'm thinking this approach may be somewhat over the top here), but there is a way to set limits, inequalities and equalities ( ``G >= 0``, ``L = 0`` ) for the restrictions, where ``G`` and ``L`` would be your defined functions

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use it together with nls command (or another one that can be used for curve fitting)

Comment: Well, you already have a f(A) defined. If you define a "least square" function, i.e., ``sum(  ( y - f(A) )^2  )``, which is the fitted non-linear line, defined by f(A), and its squared differences from your data ``y``. By minimizing this you're essentially doing non-linear least squares (hence ``nls``), you'd just have to define another function L(y,A) (see, i.e., (Augmented) Lagrangian multipliers), which would calculate those summed squares. ``Rsolnp`` would take care of minimizing the function, but with the imposed restrictions you were asking about.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: This feels more like a question for https://math.stackexchange.com, where you can get help figuring out the maths involved, before you start making R do that thing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think such question would get redirected back here or to CrossValidated, if posted at mathSE :) Anyway, these communities often overlap

Comment: @RodrigoCrespoMiguel great, glad to help!

Comment: @Nutle except in this case it's a problem about the maths first, because any code.